# Segfault with linked lists in C

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I'm writing a program involving linked lists for my current CS class, and one function in particular keeps causing a segmentation fault when I call it. The function is below:

```
void addSong(Playlist *theList, char *name, char *title, char *artist, int minutes, int seconds) {
    /*
        1. Make sure a playlist by that name exists (so you can add a song to it)
        2. Make sure the song does not already exist in the playlist (title/artist)
        3. Add the new song to the end of the songlist in that playlist (add-at-end)
    */
    Playlist *Pointer = theList;
    while(1){//Find the list
        if(strcmp(Pointer->name, name) == 0)
            break;
        if(Pointer->next == NULL){
            printf("There is no playlist by that name.\n");
            return;
        }
        Pointer = Pointer->next;
    }
    Song *playPoint = Pointer->songlist;
    while(1){//Find the end of the list
        if(playPoint == NULL){
            Song *Songy = malloc(sizeof(Song));
            Songy->title = title;
            Songy->artist = artist;
            Songy->minutes = minutes;
            Songy->seconds = seconds;
            Pointer->songlist = Songy;
        }
        if(strcmp(playPoint->title, title) == 0 && strcmp(playPoint->artist, artist) == 0){
            printf("There is already a song by that title and artist.");
            return;
        }
        if(playPoint->next == NULL){
            break;
        }
        playPoint = playPoint->next;
    }
    Song *Songy = malloc(sizeof(Song));
    Songy->title = title;
    Songy->artist = artist;
    Songy->minutes = minutes;
    Songy->seconds = seconds;
    playPoint->next = Songy;    //Add the song to the end of the list
    return;
}
```

If it matters, here are the two structs referenced:

```
typedef struct song {
    char *title;
    char *artist;
    int minutes;
    int seconds;
    struct song *next;
} Song;

typedef struct playlist {
    char *name;
    Song *songlist;
    struct playlist *next;
} Playlist;
```

What am I doing to cause the segfault?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: You should split this into two parts: one that finds the playlist, and one that adds a song to it. That will make it easier to see which one is at fault as well as just being generally cleaner. You can also pass a `struct song` as an argument instead of all its fields separately.

Comment: As posted (with no main entry point), code won't do any segmentation fault....

Comment: Anyway, one problem is that you’re not initializing the `next`s of the songs you add. As MD XF points out, a debugger could help a lot here; even if you don’t know how to use it to inspect the state of the program, it will at least tell you which line the segfault occurred on.

Answer (score 4):

You did not post enough information to make it possible to someone to spot exactly where your segfault occurs. Consider isolating it in a [MCVE example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

However, a seg fault could occur for sure when `playPoint == NULL` in your second while loop, as you end up using it anyway by accessing `playPoint->title`:

```
if(playPoint == NULL){
    Song *Songy = malloc(sizeof(Song));
    Songy->title = title;
    Songy->artist = artist;
    Songy->minutes = minutes;
    Songy->seconds = seconds;
    Pointer->songlist = Songy;
}
// here, playPoint is still equal to NULL!! COde from your if statement did not change that!
// accessing playPoint->title and playPoint->artist will crash for sure (seg fault)
if(strcmp(playPoint->title, title) == 0 && strcmp(playPoint->artist, artist) == 0){
    printf("There is already a song by that title and artist.");
    return;
}
```

You probably meant:

```
if(playPoint == NULL){
        playPoint = malloc(sizeof(Song));
        playPoint->title = title;
        playPoint->artist = artist;
        playPoint->minutes = minutes;
        playPoint->seconds = seconds;
        Pointer->songlist = playPoint;
}
```

but it's hard to guess...

But there could be other sources of segfault in this code (like Songy->next not being set, like Ryan commented) + in other code you did not post.

You probably wrote too much code before you started testing it and you probably have many places when things are done wrong and could lead to seg faults. Consider starting your project again from scratch and add things by iterations (testing and validating each iteration)....or use a debgger to fix them all...